# Creating a VSTO Add in for multible applications

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

Is it possible to create an VSTO add in for multible office applications?

Can I outsource the functions i want to have for every application and then create an Add-in for every application? If yes, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend making a `solution` with an `add-in project` for each Office application.

Then add a `class library` project to the solution and reference that from each of the add-on projects.

That way you can centralize code used in all add-ins.

If you need to interact with the active application or document, you can detect the type of the calling object and typecast it to the relevant application/document type.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can just put your common functions into a shared DLL, just like any other application. Since each VSTO project targets a different application structure and potentially UI paradigm, I'd recommend having different VSTO projects in a single solution, and a shared assembly holding the common code.

Answer (score 0):

**VSTO** doesn't support creating multi-host add-ins. You need to create separate projects for each host and use a class library for the shared code base.

Note, [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) allows creating multi-host COM add-ins. So, a single add-in project can be run in multiple hosts. It comes from the *IDTExtensibility2* interface. I don't know why VSTO creators didn't provide such feature to developers.

Comment: This used to be support, but has been discouninued. There is still away of doing this:https://davecra.com/2015/10/28/a-complete-shared-add-in-template/

Answer (score 0):

VSTO itself doesn't provide such an option. If you want to get single project for all application you can use shim add-in. That makes possible to run add-in in all applications from the same dll. The only issue -- your code need to handle what application started to call it to run separate logic or to call specific office API functions.